# Logic behind trackPageView questionable?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I am i doubt that the logic behind salesforce trackPageView is working as intended. That is the reason why i wanted to ask if anybody else solved the following problem through work-arounds or different logic in the product catalog. Following we see the sample product catalog of SFMC:

```
SkuID|ProductCode|ProductName|ProductType|ProductLink|ImageLink|RegularPrice|SalePrice|BrandName|Color|Rating|NumReviews|ReleaseDate|Keywords
12384|XCode12384|Brand B Whiz 9039|Headphones|http://www.companyx.com/products/12384|http://www.companyx.com/images/12384.jpg|8.87||Brand B|Green|4|3|10/5/2012|Music
12385|XCode12385|Brand B Whiz 9040|Headphones|http://www.companyx.com/products/12385|http://www.companyx.com/images/12385.jpg|27.86||Brand B|Green|4|3|10/6/2012|Music
12386|XCode12385|Brand B Whiz 9041|Headphones|http://www.companyx.com/products/12386|http://www.companyx.com/images/12386.jpg|49.85||Brand B|Green|4|3|10/7/2012|Music
12387|XCode12385|Brand B Whiz 9042|Headphones|http://www.companyx.com/products/12387|http://www.companyx.com/images/12387.jpg|28.21||Brand B|Green|4|3|10/8/2012|Music
12388|XCode12385|Brand B Whiz 9043|Headphones|http://www.companyx.com/products/12388|http://www.companyx.com/images/12388.jpg|44.86||Brand B|Red|2.3|3|10/9/2012|Music
```

Salesforce creates an own unique code which is stored in the field UUID in the product catalog [can be seen trhough reporting-admin tools]. When multiple articles share the same productcode of XCode12385 salesforce will give them uuids like XCode12385~1, XCode12385~2, XCode12385~3, XCode12385~4, ... .

The problem is that trackPageView will only track against the uuid with XCode12385~1. This is especially contraproductive when the user-attributes [top 5 affinities] will be correlated towards the first articles. Maybe the user only likes red color and browsed the article with the SkuID 12388 a lot, then the color affinity will be based on the first articles which is green.

Does anybody has an idea how to workaround this when you still want to be able  to differentiate between products and articles in your productcatalog?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you get any clarity in this? Also saw this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203940/how-to-match-trackingcode-to-productcatalog I am in the exact same position with the same questions.

Comment: This begs the question, why do you have multiple articles sharing the same product code? You should not have duplicates in your catalogue.

Comment: Assume you have a shoe. It comes in different sizes. Each size has its own skuid but the same productcode. Easily described. Its even in the sample code of salesforce ;)